Fuchsian Group acts on Extended Complex Plane, but not discontinuously
I'm looking for an example of a Fuchsian group that acts discontinuously on the upper half-plane
$\mathbb{H}$, but fails to do so on the entire extended complex plane $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ . My approach is to think about a subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that for some point $z \in \hat{\mathbb{C}}$, the orbit which contains of points of the form $\frac{ax+b}{cz+d}$ has no limit point.
where $$\gamma= \Big( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \Big) \in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$$
My understanding is that a subgroup $\Gamma$ of group of homeomorphisms of the topological space $X$ acts discontinuously if the orbits have no limit point in $X$. Is this understanding correct?
The book I am referring to is Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms by Iwaniec, but I am reframing some of the statements in a way I understand better.
Then further mention that if the action of $\Gamma$ on $X$ is discontinuous then there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $\{ \gamma \in \Gamma : \gamma U \cap U \neq \phi\}=\Gamma_x$ where $\Gamma_x$ is the subgroup of \Gamma which fixes the point $x$.

Your definition of a properly discontinuous action in wrong. If this is what your book says, consider reading a different source.

Aren't discontinuous and properly discontinuos different?

Your understanding of the meaning of discontinuity is correct. However, regarding your approach as stated in your first paragraph, I think you might have garbled the logic. To prove that $\Gamma$ fails to be discontinuous you must find some point $z \in \mathbb C^*$ whose orbit does have a limit point.

One simple example is $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$. First, the orbit of $0$ contains $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R^*$, because for every $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Q$ in lowest terms, we pick $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ such that $pm+qn=1$, and then we use $f(z) = \frac{qz+m}{-pz+n}$. Also, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R^*$, so every element of $\mathbb R^*$ is a limit point of the orbit of $0$.

In fact it is a theorem that if $\Gamma < PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ is any infinite subgroup that acts discontinuously on $\mathbb H$ then $\Gamma$ does not act discontinuously on $\mathbb C^*$. First one uses discontinuity on $\mathbb H$ to argue that there exists $\gamma \in \Gamma$ that is not an elliptic element. Then one argues that $\gamma$ has a fixed point in $p \in \mathbb R^*$: either $\gamma$ is parabolic and has a unique fixed point in $\mathbb R^*$; or $\gamma$ is hyperbolic and has two fixed points in $\mathbb R^*$. Finally one argues that any fixed point $p$ of $\gamma$ is a limit point of the orbit of any point that is not fixed by $\gamma$.

Let $x$ be any positive real number $\ne 1$ and consider $\Gamma = \langle\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}x^{1/2}&0 \\ 0&x^{-1/2}\end{pmatrix}\rangle\subset\operatorname{PSL}_2(\Bbb R)$. Then $\alpha$ acts on $\hat{\Bbb C}$ by multiplication by $x$ which restricts to a discontinuous action on the upper half plane. But of course the action is not discontinuous on $\hat{\Bbb C}$, for example $\Gamma1=\{x^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$ has limit point $0$.
